# Are mobile network operators known to make offers based on usage statistics?

Tags: mobile-phone-plans

For quite some time I exclusively used a mobile internet connection. A couple of weeks ago my landlord installed WiFi in the building and my mobile data usage dropped by orders of magnitude. I haven't gotten around to checking out rates and maybe switching to a cheaper contract, but it might be a good idea.

I got a text message informing me that because of my "loyalty" I was from now on getting a 40% more expensive contract for the same price I paid before (free unlimited calls and some data in several additional countries). Unless I terminate the contract, of course.

There is no doubt the mobile phone provider could send out such offers automatically based on a calculation of the likeliness someone quits, forecast of what the offer costs them, profitability of customer, etc.

Is there evidence some of them actually do this? Are data protection laws relevant to this?

Comment: sure, they do this as a matter of course, millions of times a month.  the system "sucks" but that's how it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of them do.

Data protection laws, need country to be specific. As much as I know, there is nothing in data protection that stops from using the data for analytics to improve the service to you.

They can't sell individual data to 3rd party, they can sell aggregated data